# Placeholder for double and single quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which returns a table of given size containing given content in each cell displaying it in the div with the given ID.

```
generate_table(4,4,'Cell Content','display')
```

To test this function I have used `onload` on my body tag. The function does work. However i wish to have an input of type number inside the cells so

```
<body onload="generate_table(4,4,'<input type='number'>','display')">
```

The problem, if you did not see it is that the string that I am passing as the content of the cells gets cut at the `'` before number.

Comment: `<body onload="generate_table(4,4,'<input type=\"number\">','display')">`  use backslachs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the characters:

```
<body onload="generate_table(4,4,'<input type=\"number\">','display')">
```

Or call the function from a JavaScript file or even embed it in your HTML file:

```
<html>
  ...
<script>
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('load', function() {
     generate_table(4,4,'<input type="number">','display')
  }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline handlers. Add a listener properly using JavaScript instead, and you won't have to worry about any escaping issues.

```
<body>
```

and, in the JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener('load', () => generate_table(4,4,'Cell Content','display'));
```